# Plotting Scientific data in .net

Tags: .net, charts, plot, data-visualization

Does anyone have any recommendations for plotting scientific data in .net (c# winforms). Some of my requirements are: real time plotting, 3D (waterfall), multiple axis, ability to accept BindingList as a data source and recognize any changes to the data. I also need a high level of user interactivity such as the ability to graphically select 1 or more series, draw regions. highlight part of a series, etc.
So far I've looked at Nevron, Synchfusion, Infragistics, TeeChart and a few others.

Answer (score 2):

Don't the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Xceed library](http://xceed.com/Chart_WinForms_Intro.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross-platform GPL plotting library [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) to produce a bitmap. Its plotting is fast and have many graphics types (including waterfall, many-axis and so on). But I'm not sure if you can use something except C-interface for .net programs.